# Fourier transformation for Neumann boundary condition above 1D

Tags: fourier-transform, boundary-conditions, differential-equations

I want to apply integral transform method to
a Poisson's equation in a sphere
$$
\nabla^2 u=f(\boldsymbol r)
$$
with Neumann boundary condition
$$
\boldsymbol n\cdot \nabla u|_{r=R}=0.
$$
Physically it should be solvalbe,
but I can't go through with Fourier transformation because it  requires the value on the boundary, $u(\boldsymbol r)|_{r=R}$.

In 1D problem, I can choose the integral kernel to be $\cos kx$ to escape from this difficulty. What shall I do in 3D instead of separating variables?

Thanks for answering.

---

In my case, the problem is a diffusion problem,
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}-D\nabla^2u=0
$$
with initial value condition
$$
u(\boldsymbol r,0)=\delta(\boldsymbol r)
$$
and boundary condition given above.
Seperating $r$ and $t$ finnaly gives
$$
u=\frac1{2\pi a^3}\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{x_i^2}{\sin^2x_i}
j_0\left(\frac{x_i}{a}r\right)
\exp\left(-\frac{x_i^2}{a^2}Dt\right),
$$
where $a$ is the radius of the sphere,
$j_0(x)$ is the zero-order Bessel function,
and $x_i$ is the $i$-th root of the first-order function $j_1(x)$.

---

By Laplace transform on $t$, the original equation becomes
$$
\omega\hat u(\boldsymbol r,\omega)-D\nabla^2 \hat u(\boldsymbol r,\omega)=\delta(\boldsymbol r).
$$
What transformation shall I take on the spatial part?
There is a $\nabla^2$ in the equation, so if I choose Fourier tranformation I need to know value of $u$ on the boundary.

The initial value condion can take other forms, including isotropic ones.
In these case separation of variables is not quite easy.
(Reminded by @basics, for anisotropy conditions the transform may be difficult, too. So my initial motivation for the transform method is not convincing. But I still wonder if there's an approach.)

Comment: Why don't you like to do separation of variables? If you do it with spherical coordinates, you can easily use harmonic functions for the periodic angle coordinate, and the set of base functions you like in the other angular and radial direction, so that they satisfy the continuity conditions in the singular points of the transformations (likely to be the poles of the sphere and the points of the axis)

Comment: @basics separation of variables usually leads to an infinite set of eigenfunctions whose  linear combination yields the solution.  In numerical calculations I have to truncate it. With intergral tranformation it's possible to get a simpler form.

Comment: Do you need to solve the equation analytically or numerically? Anyway, even if use other numerical methods, the solution is discrete, i.e. finite dimensional (as an example, Finite Difference methods gives you a finite number of point values of the functions, Finite Elements gives you the result as a combination of a finite set of base functions definite on compact elements): for general expression of the forcing $f(\mathbf{r})$, it's likely that you can't find a easy way to write the solution in a closed form without relying on infinite series to be truncated or numericial approximations

Comment: @basics I need to solve it analytically, and the solution will be numerically calculated for further studying.   $f(r)$ has a definite expression in my case, but of little significance in this post. I've already solved it by separating variables, and the numerical calculation doesn't behave very well.

Comment: could you provide us with the expression of $f(\mathbf{r})$?

Comment: @basics I made an edit. Thanks for patience.